# Regex not getting whole link at special characters

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, hyperlink, preg-replace

I am using this code:

```
$string = preg_replace("~(?!(?:https?://(?:www\.)?|www\.)(?:youtube\.com)(?:https?://(?:www\.)?|www\.)[\w./=?#-]+~i", '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $string);
```

So that I can turn the link beneath into a clickable link.

```
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/Bill_Clinton%2C_Yitzhak_Rabin,%2C_Yasser_Arafat_at_the_White_House_1993-09-13.jpg
```

This works for a part... It makes a link of `http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/Bill_Clinton` but the rest stays plain text. How can I make it work for the whole link? So you see a `comma` too... How can I make that a link?

Comment: you'd have to allow for `%` in your regex, it's not part of the `\w`  character class.

Comment: It _looks_ like changing `[\w./=?#-]` to `[\w./=?#-%]` would fix it.

Comment: Damn, I tried that. But I had added the % before the `\w`. Let me check it.

Comment: Order doesn't matter except for the hyphen.

Comment: I see. Now I get stuck on a `comma`. How can I add that one? I tried `[,.]` in the `[\w./=?#-]`, but did not work

Comment: Why would there be _two_ colons after the https?

Comment: Better solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900004/turn-plain-text-urls-into-active-links-using-php/17900021#17900021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also I'm trying to account for punctuation at the end of a URL (so that we don't include it).

```
<?php

$string = "This works http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/Bill_Clinton%2C_Yitzhak_Rabin%2C_Yasser_Arafat_at_the_White_House_1993-09-13.jpg. This one should fail http://www.youtube.com/v/adlskdfjasopie. Although this one should fail as well http://youtu.be/adlkajdaslk.";

$string = preg_replace("~(?!(?:https?://(?:www\.)?|www\.)(?:youtu))(?:https?://(?:www\.)?|www\.)[^\s]+[^.!?,\<\]\[\)(]~i",'<a href="$0">$0</a>',$string);


?>
```

**output**

```
This works <a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/Bill_Clinton%2C_Yitzhak_Rabin%2C_Yasser_Arafat_at_the_White_House_1993-09-13.jpg. ">http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/Bill_Clinton%2C_Yitzhak_Rabin%2C_Yasser_Arafat_at_the_White_House_1993-09-13.jpg. </a>This one should fail http://www.youtube.com/v/adlskdfjasopie. Although this one should fail as well http://youtu.be/adlkajdaslk.
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does override my code, which I have made to exclude Youtube links. So in this case it is not the answer I am looking for. Can you enhance my own code?

Comment: @Johan Updated my code to show that. Also by not using all of youtube.com and only specifying "youtu" that allows you to filter out youtu.be addresses as well.

Comment: Brother, I appreciate your help, but I need to use the same structure (preg_replace), and no other variables or content, because I am using Wordpress.

Comment: @Johan ah. Simple enough fix.

Comment: @ Absolutezero: your code get's the `</p>` in which the link is wrapped in too. Can you fix that?

Comment: It's reserved. You'll have to escape it. I've updated my code.

Comment: Nope, the newly updated code does not work. THe other one did. Your new code still gets the `</p>`

Comment: Update your code to show the sample code (above) to show the `<p>` tag you're trying to avoid.