# Regex not getting comma, plus and x in url's

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace

I am using this regex:

```
$string = preg_replace("~(?!(?:https?://(?:www\.)?|www\.)(?:youtube\.com))(?:https?://(?:www\.)?|www\.)[\w./=?#-%:-]+~i",
                       '<a target="_blank" href="$0">$0</a>', $string);
```

But I can't get it to show the link here as clickable text:

```
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_mGMUxSe_j0I/R24t5bmY2nI/AAAAAAAAAs4/ndqvaJ1Z-oY/s400/chernobyl+-+multiple+sclerosis.jpg
```

It just makes a link until the *+-+*, where it stops makin it clickable. It becomes plain text once again.

```
http://chornobyl.in.ua/wp-content/uploads/photo-wolf-640×250.jpg
```

This don't show the things after *640* in a link (so does not get the x).

If I add a `+` or a `x` in `[\w./=?#-%:-]`, **it gets my whole `</p>` tag in which the link is wrapped**. I honestly don't know what to do. Can somone help me out?

Comment: This is basically the exact same question as your last one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864523/regex-not-getting-whole-link-at-special-characters  The **EXACT** same concept holds.

Comment: No it's not. There, it didn't get the whole `</p>` tag, but now it is. Besides, I managed to solve the `_` and `&` problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function superLinks($text)
{
    $ret = ' ' . $text;

    // http:// & https://
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[^ \"\n\r\t<]*)#is", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
    // www & ftp
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[^ \"\t\n\r<]*)#is", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
    // mail
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([a-z0-9&\-_.]+?)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+\.)*[\w]+)#i", "\\1<a href=\"mailto:\\2@\\3\">\\2@\\3</a>", $ret);
    // youtube
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((youtube)\.[^ \"\n\r\t<]*)#is", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);

    $ret = substr($ret, 1);

    return $ret;
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Better solution [Turn Plain Text URLs into Active Links using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900004/turn-plain-text-urls-into-active-links-using-php/17900021#17900021)

Comment: Can you include the http(s), www and Youtube exceptions? Because that is very important for me... Beside it gives me a `Warning: preg_replace() expects parameter 4 to be long, string given in ` error

Comment: Thanks, but there is no Youtube exception once again... and it did not get a single link. Not working bro.

Comment: Youtube like `youtu.be/idofvideo`?

Comment: Nope, Youtube like it is on the first post.

Comment: Ok. Ok... You know... I can't write parse for `site.com` becous someone can write `I like my dog.be happy`. Now it's `100%` done.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34185/discussion-between-maciej-czyzewski-and-johan)